# Enabling desktop experience from C# on windows 2008 / 2012

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am currently using command:

```
servermanagercmd -install Desktop-Experience
```

From what I read, I understood that this is no longer supported in Windows 2012.

I understood that can be done from PowerShell cmdlet somehow but can't find an example
for a need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the PS script you're looking for is:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `Add-WindowsFeature` command will work back in 2008.  DISM is the best route for all versions involved.

```
Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:DesktopExperience /All
```