# What is the best way to enable Windows feature programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to turn "Desktop Experience" Windows feature on. Is it possible to do it using C# and do not involve user in this process (or with minimal involving)? What it is the best way to do it?

**UPD:** PowerShell Add-WindowsFeature is not a solution, because the ServerManager commands are only available from 64 bit version of PowerShell

Comment: Just read this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406939/enabling-desktop-experience-from-c-sharp-on-windows-2008-2012][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406939/enabling-desktop-experience-from-c-sharp-on-windows-2008-2012

Comment: What if the user does not have PowerShell? Can I install PowerShell at his PC automatically?

Comment: Use this: http://devonenote.com/2010/07/install-powershell-from-command-line/

Comment: Do not run around installing stuff on a server behind the user's back. Just say "This program requires the Desktop Experience feature" and let the administrator decide what to do next. (It will probably be either to install the Desktop Experience, or to uninstall your app.)

Answer (score 1):

You can install "Desktop Experience" using Powershell.

This article desribes it:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2013/07/11/install-desktop-experience-on-windows-server-2012.aspx

IMHO it's easier than going the C# route.

Comment: It is for Windows PowerShell 4.0. What if the user does not have it? Can install PowerShell at his PC automatically?